# How to choose covariate adjustment method for effect of treatment estimation?

Tags: python, causality, propensity-scores, treatment-effect, confounding

When trying to estimate average treatment effect (ATE) how does one choose between the different methods available to adjust for confounders?

For example, how to choose between propensity score block matching, regression with propensity score weights, nearest neighbour covariate matching, etc ...

Is there any method that is currently considered best, or are there any rules to help one choose a method over others?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Favored methods for overcoming selection bias (special attention to healthcare fields)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422710/favored-methods-for-overcoming-selection-bias-special-attention-to-healthcare-f)

Comment: Partly, yes thank you. However, I was wondering if there were some clear rules/restrictions where one ought to avoid one method over others. Do you know any references where these are clearly laid out?